# generate sequential strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im making a javascript game, and I want to generate enemies, but this does not seem to work

```
var Monster = function(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

var spawnMonsters = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < spawn; i++) {
        var name = "Monster";
        name += i;
        name = new Monster(Math.random()*canvas.width-16,0); 
    }     
};
```

help please? Though I can generate multiple enemies by hard-coding each monster name. such as Monster2=new Monster(Math.random()*canvas.width-16,0); Monster3=...... etc

Comment: What _does not seem to work_? What do you expect your code to do vs what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

In javascript you cannot use "variable variables" as you could do, for example, in PHP.

You could try this:

```
var monsters = [];

function spawn(num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    monster.push(new Monster(Math.random() * canvas.width - 16, 0));
  }
}
```

now `monsters` will be an array of all the monsters you spawned.

Comment: Well you *can* use variable variables, either by using `eval` or by poking them into the scope object concerned (e.g. `window` in a browser). However you *shouldn't* do that for various reasons, so this approach is a much better one.

Comment: Thanks Matteo! lastly, how can I use that array of monsters to be drawn by this function

var drawMonsters=function(){
for (var i=0;i<spawn;i++){
     var name = "Monster";
     name+=i;
 ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, name.x, name.y);
 }
        
};

Comment: In your function, it is not clear from where `monsterImage` does come.

Answer (score 0):

You can genarate Strings like:

```
function makeid()
{
var text = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

return text;
}
```